# creating/saving folder in wrong directory

Tags: python

i have problem creating a folder into a specif directory. The folder will always be created in cwd and not in my savepath! The savepath directory exists already. Please check my Code. Thank You

```
savepath_log = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test_folder'

# get folder path
cwd = os.getcwd()

if not os.path.exists(savepath_log):
    savepath_log = cwd

ns=100
bnr=9999
self.bnr=bnr

# create folders
        self.fov = "%s_Ablegen" %self.bnr
        self.create_folder(self.fov,savepath_log)  
        
# imwrite: save image
        self.hl_ov = '%s/%s/image_%d.png' %(savepath_log, self.fov, ns)
        img.save(self.hl_ov, 'png')

def create_folder(self,fname,fpath):

        dir = os.path.join(fpath,fname)

        if os.path.exists(dir):
            shutil.rmtree(dir)               
            
        os.mkdir(dir)
```

Comment: Please check your indentation, especially on the `# create folders` and `# imwrite: save image` sections. This code as written will not run.

Comment: A [mre] needs to run _as written_ and demonstrate the issue you are having. Simply deleting some part of your code doesn't make it a MRE. For example, it appears your functions were part of a class. Either include a reduced version of that class, or remove the dependence on `self`.